# Given an array of length n, find number of subsets where XOR of a subset is equal to a given number

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation, dynamic-programming

Given an array, `arr`, of length `n`, find how many subsets of `arr` there are such that `XOR(^)` of those subsets is equal to a given number, `ans`.

I have this `dp` approach but is there a way to improve its time complexity. `ans` is always less than 1024.

Here `ans` is the no. such that `XOR(^)` of the subsets is equal to it.
`arr[n]` contains all the numbers

```
memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
dp[0][0] = 1;

for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
        dp[i][j] = (dp[i-1][j] + dp[i-1][j^arr[i]]);
    }
}

cout << (dp[n][ans]);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: `dp` is the right way to go. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @MohitJain How can i improve its time complexity

Comment: I am getting TLE. N is of the order 10^5.

Comment: Are all the numbers in the array less than 1024?

Comment: Then it seems like you should be able to exploit the repetition in the input array. Given that the input has 10^5 numbers, but only 10^3 unique values are possible, then on average each value appears 100 times in the input. And one of the properties of XOR is that XORing a number with itself an even number of times yields 0, and an odd number of times yields the number. Combine those two observations, and you should be able to speed things up considerably.

Comment: @MohitJain I am talking about the identifier in OP's code

Comment: @M.M; "dynamic programming". I just picked that up from comments on answers below.

Comment: It just hit me, while re-reading the question... since we are talking about **subSETs**, please specify what an **element** would be. If the position of a number in the array is part of an element, the array `arr[] = { 1, 1 }` would have 4 subsets (empty, 1st, 2nd, both numbers), but otherwise only 2 subsets (empty and { 1 })

Comment: This seems to be the same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136955/finding-the-no-of-subset-with-a-given-xor#comment56086226_34136955

Comment: waiting for some better answer

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf in case you aren't trolling, I am asking to see the declaration of the identifier `dp`

Comment: @M.M: Oh, it's just a 2D array, a matrix, of `int` presumably, but possibly `unsigned`. It's needlessly very large (the code can be adjusted to just toggle between two arrays, instead of having at least `n` arrays).

Answer (score 2):

From [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148742/given-an-array-of-length-n-find-number-of-subsets-where-xor-of-a-subset-is-equa#comment56047309_34148742)'s comment, building on top of your code:

```
/* Warning: Untested */
int counts[1024] = {0}, ways[1024];
for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) counts[ arr[i] ] += 1;
for(int i = 0; i <= 1024; ++i) {
  const int z = counts[i];
  // Look for overflow here
  ways[i] = z == 0 ?
              0 :
              (int)(1U << (z-1));
}

memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
dp[0][0] = 1;

for(i = 1; i <= 1024; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
        // Check for overflow
        const int howmany = ways[i] * dp[i-1][j];
        dp[i][j] += howmany;
        dp[i][j^i] += howmany;
    }
}

cout << (dp[1024][ans]);
```

For calculating `odd_` and `even_`, you can also use the following:

> <sup>n</sup>c<sub>0</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>2</sub>+... =
>   <sup>n</sup>c<sub>1</sub>+<sup>n</sup>c<sub>3</sub>... =
>   2<sup>n-1</sup>

Because number of ways to select odd items = number of ways to reject odd items = number of ways to select even numbers

You can also optimize the space by keeping just 2 columns of dp arrays and reusing them as `dp[i-2][x]` are discarded.

Comment: I think the number of ways is smaller. For example, if the input is {4,1,1,1} and the target is 5, then the valid subsets are {4,1} and {4,1,1,1}. So the number of ways to select an odd number of 1's is `(z+1)/2`. The number of ways to select an even number of 1's would be `(z+2)/2`.

Comment: Thanks @user3386109. I assumed 1s at different indices would be count different. i.e. {4, 1} can be selected in 3 ways and {4, 1, 1, 1} in 1 way.

Comment: It seems that the code in the question will count {4,1} three times, but I'm not convinced that's what the code *should* do. I guess it's up to the OP to decide :)

Comment: @MohitJain Don't u think this solution is wrong ?

Comment: @ankitkumar It might be. Can you please elaborate more what might be wrong. This answer provides more of direction/hint to implement the final solution .I will write a test case to compare with OP's version whenever I get some extra minutes.

Comment: @MohitJain What will be ur code's output if ans is 1023 ans array elements are {0,0} ?

Comment: @MohitJain I think u can write tested and more clear code.

Comment: This question is from the ongoing contest [Codechef December Long Challenge](https://www.codechef.com/DEC15/problems/CHEFFILT) :P

Answer (score 1):

The Idea behind dynamic programming is, to (1) never compute the same result twice and (2) only compute results at demand and not precompute the whole thing as you do it.

So there is a solution needed for `solve(arr, n, ans)` with `ans < 1024`, `n < 1000000` and `arr = array[n]`. The idea of having `dp[n][ans]` holding the number of results is reasonable, so dp size is needed as `dp = array[n+1][1024]`. What we need is a way to distinguish between not yet computed results and available results. So `memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp))` and then as you already did `dp[0][0] = 1`

```
solve(arr, n, ans):
    if (dp[n][ans] == -1)
        if (n == 0) // and ans != 0 since that was initialized already
            dp[n][ans] = 0
        else
            // combine results with current and without current array element
            dp[n][ans] = solve(arr + 1, n - 1, ans) + solve(arr + 1, n - 1, ans XOR arr[0])
    return dp[n][ans]
```

The advantage is, that your `dp` array is only partially computed on the way to your solution, so this might save some time.

Depending on the stack size and `n`, it might be necessary to translate this from a recursive to an iterative solution

Comment: Most theoretical descriptions of dynamic programming seem to imply your idea (2).  But virtually all practical applications of dynamic programming throw that away.  Knowing which results you will need ends up massively increasing the memory requirements of the solution and detecting which you have already computed (vs. computing them in a predictable sequence) would massively increase the time required.

Comment: @JSF Yea, I had to increase the stack size a fair bit for this (was working), so I tried to transform it to some sort of work queue solution, then things started to be awkward. So I guess a good solution will really have to deal with details like compressing the count of duplicate input numbers.