# find number of combinations where XOR of each combination is equal to a given number

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, xor

Given an array, `arr`, of length `n`, find how many subsets of `arr` there are such that `XOR(^)` of those subsets is equal to a given number, `total`.

I have this `dp` approach but it taking too much time. `total` is always less than 1024 and also `arr[n]` always less than 1024.

```
memset(answer,0,sizeof(answer));
answer[0][total]=1;
answer[0][total^arr[0]]=answer[0][total^arr[0]]+1;
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<1024; j++)
    {
        answer[(i%2)][j]=(answer[(i-1)%2][j]%MOD+answer[(i-1)%2][j^arr[i]]%MOD)%MOD;
    }
}
return answer[(n-1)%2][0];
```

The question is asked here [Given an array of length n, find number of subsets where XOR of a subset is equal to a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148742/given-an-array-of-length-n-find-number-of-subsets-where-xor-of-a-subset-is-equa) but the question is not having any better solutions which are required. Can anybody help to optimise this.

Comment: @mepcotterell I already mentioned. I think you don't read my question well.

Comment: It's the same question. If you want better answers, invest some time in the site and then set a bounty.